# Regex:Match and Replace a pattern from string while keeping a part of matched string in the replaced string

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have a string like

```
@jhon.p @[User:151|Jhon Carter] Jhon Carter @sunil.p @[User:102|Sunil Nadar] Sunil Nadar
```

I want to apply regex in javascript OR Java to the above string to get the output as

```
@jhon.p <a href="#/users/151">Jhon Carter</a> @sunil.p <a href="#/users/102">Sunil Nadar</a>
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex to match

```
@\[User:(\d+)\|(.*?)\]\s*\2
```

and then you can use this to replace where $1 $2 refer to the groups.

```
<a href="#/users/$1">$2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the Java code that will do the job for you:

```
String str =
 "@jhon.p @[User:151|Jhon Carter] Jhon Carter @sunil.p @[User:102|Sunil Nadar] Sunil Nadar";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("@\\[User:(\\d+)\\|([^]]+)\\]\\s+\\2").matcher(str);
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
   String link = "<a href=\"#/users/" + m.group(1) + "\">" + m.group(2) + "</a>";
   m.appendReplacement(buf, link);
}
m.appendTail(buf);
System.out.printf("Converted String is: %s%n", buf);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Converted String is: @jhon.p <a href="#/users/151">Jhon Carter</a> @sunil.p <a href="#/users/102">Sunil Nadar</a>
```